Is it possible to get a C-u (repeat 4 times) shortcut in PyCharm?
In Emacs there is a super-useful command C-u (Ctrl + u) which repeats the next command 4 times. This enables things like moving very quickly through lines of text without going to the mouse.
Is there an equivalent in PyCharm? Or something similar?

Did my answer help?

As of today, this is not possible and is still a requested feature for all IntelliJ apps. No plugin with this functionality is to be found on marketplace either.
I would recommend to use an application like AutoHotkey instead. This is an example of a script that should work:
^u:: ; Ctrl + u
  ih := InputHook("T5 M") ; Read any kind of input (M) for 5 seconds (T5)
  ih.Start()
  ih.Wait() ; Wait until it finishes
  loop, 4
  {
    Send, % ih.Input ; Send the recorded input 4 times
  }

You could also use #IfWinActive to limit it to PyCharm if needed.
